# VS Code: can't compile c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

When I click 'Start Debugging' in visual code I receive this error. No google results have worked so how do I fix it? I'm trying to compile C# code.

```
The preLaunchTask 'build' terminated with exit code 1.
```

I have added some code below of my launch.json file and the other file for my VS code as I wasn't sure if it would help being able to see them.

launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "console": "internalConsole"
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (web)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/Debug/<target-framework>/<project-name.dll>",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "launchBrowser": {
                "enabled": true,
                "args": "${auto-detect-url}",
                "windows": {
                    "command": "cmd.exe",
                    "args": "/C start ${auto-detect-url}"
                },
                "osx": {
                    "command": "open"
                },
                "linux": {
                    "command": "xdg-open"
                }
            },
            "env": {
                "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
            },
            "sourceFileMap": {
                "/Views": "${workspaceRoot}/Views"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": ".NET Core Attach",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "attach",
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}"
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "args": [ ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "showOutput": "silent",
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a `preLaunchTask` configured in your launch.json file. It is the task that gets run before the script is executed. That task is 'build', from your tasks.json file. It is failing, as indicated by its return of a non-zero error code. You need to open up your tasks.json configuration file, see what the 'build' task entails, and then figure out why it is failing.

Comment: I have updated my question with the tasks.json and launch.json, would you please take a look? Thanks.